# How do I retain the state of a data input screen on a ASP.NET Page using ExtJs Controls

Tags: asp.net, extjs, state, savestate

My Client has an application that is built in ASP.NET (c#) that makes use of a lot of ExtJS controls.

I need to enable the application to save every thing on the entry screen to a temporary storage mechanism and when necessary restore it.

The scenorio is the user has captured some data to a specific screen but is unable to continue and then there session expires.

If this happens and the user then logs in, it needs to restore there data/

Are there any good ideas I can investigate this type of thing.

I would like to make it as simple and robust as possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can always store data on disk IO or a database and tie the information to their application user ID.  That's one way, and have a button to save the incomplete form.  Are you looking to save on the fly (auto-save)?

Could you provide more details?